# Is it possible to crack a blowfish 256 bits encrypted file?

Tags: encryption

I have a file of my own that I have encrypted using Coder-Abi. Now, I can just remember part of this password. So, would it be possible (much easier) for me to crack it knowing only part of it? I can remember around 20 of them. The files are pictures, excel and word files.

If there's any software (mainly freeware), please let me know.

Comment: Beware you may have to write your own script to do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is brute force. If you know a significant proportion of the original password, (e.g., 13 characters out of 16), it wouldn't be too time consuming for a script to attempt all other possible combinations for the remaining characters.